# Game Center showing "NO ITEMS"

Tags: ios, leaderboard

I have an app I am working on that has gamecenter leaderboards, everything was working, now suddenly when I go to game center in the app the game center window literally shows nothing, just the name of the app and a big old NO ITEMS in the middle of the window.

This is only happening on my physical device, simulators the Game Center is showing up properly... do I need to reset something on my physical device?

I haven't touched the code, and when I open the game center app itself I see my apps sandbox and the leadboards are there and properly updating... Here is the show game center window code from my app, hasn't been changed or touched.

```
- (void) showGameCenter
{
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];


    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the App in device; then, Clean & Rebuild in Xcode to device

Comment: Tried, no change, still get "NO ITEMS"

Comment: Check bundle version in info.plist and in iTunesConnect. Both of them must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if `gamekit` is missing from `Required device capabilities` in your plist.